# Phase transition between two CFTs

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, string-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

If we start with a CFT (say CFT$_1$) and deform it by some relevant operator, in the IR we can get another CFT (say CFT$_2$). This is flowing from one CFT to another.

I was wondering whether there can be some example of phase transition between two CFTs. For example, suppose in 2D there are tow theories : CFT$_1$ with central charge, $c=2$ and CFT$_2$ with $c=1$ and they are separated by a phase boundary. Are there any known examples of this kind?